# Reactjs Browser Tab Close Event

Tags: reactjs

Hi I want to know how to prompt a message on browser tab close.
I am using Reactjs.

```
handleWindowClose(){
    alert("Alerted Browser Close");
},
componentDidMount: function() {
    window.addEventListener('onbeforeunload', this.handleWindowClose);
},

componentWillUnmount: function() {
    window.removeEventListener('onbeforeunload', this.handleWindowClose);
}
```

this is what I have tried adding to my react component.Please guide me on how to proceed further.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

What you did is correct apart from the event name and the fact that alert will be blocked in that particular event.

You can show a message like this:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", (ev) => 
{  
    ev.preventDefault();
    return ev.returnValue = 'Are you sure you want to close?';
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks..that worked..
However I am not able to remove the event listener on componentWillUnmount.is it the correct event.??

Comment: You can store handler in local field: `this.handler = (ev) => ...` during initialization in constructor. Then use this field in `addEventListener("beforeunload", this.handler)` and `removeEventListener("beforeunload", this.handler)` methods correspondingly.

Comment: Works like butter..Thanks a lot

Comment: Newer versions of Chrome and other browsers no longer allow you to customize this string. https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5349061406228480

Comment: where did I call this function?

Comment: This is not working only for closing tab, also works for refresh and many more cases, if you want to only listen when you close the page this wont work.

Comment: Even I need it only for the closing of the tab but not for a refresh or any other event. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 30):

Amid's answer worked well for me.

The way I used it:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
    // Things to do before unloading/closing the tab
    doSomethingBeforeUnload = () => {
        // Do something
    }

    // Setup the `beforeunload` event listener
    setupBeforeUnloadListener = () => {
        window.addEventListener("beforeunload", (ev) => {
            ev.preventDefault();
            return this.doSomethingBeforeUnload();
        });
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        // Activate the event listener
        this.setupBeforeUnloadListener();
    }

    // Render method.
    render() {
        return (
            <div>My component</div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 25):

I needed to fire logic after the user decided to close the tab.
Here is my solution (for functional react components & TypeScript):

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', alertUser)
    window.addEventListener('unload', handleTabClosing)
    return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', alertUser)
        window.removeEventListener('unload', handleTabClosing)
    }
})

const handleTabClosing = () => {
    removePlayerFromGame()
}

const alertUser = (event:any) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    event.returnValue = ''
}
```

**alertUser** warns the user with the default browser dialog.
**handleTabClosing** is fired when the user chooses to close the tab.

I have derived my solution from [this](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/how-to-alert-a-user-before-leaving-a-page-in-react-a2858104ca94) blog post from Mike Pottebaum

Answer (score 14):

One can use hooks now to implement the same. e.g.

```
import { useBeforeunload } from 'react-beforeunload';
```

and then in your component use:

```
 useBeforeunload(() => "Are you sure to close this tab?");
```

Though we are returning custom string, it will show browser's default message here.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to display a sort of confirmation before leaving the page then follow the [beforeunload event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event) guidelines:

> According to the specification, to show the confirmation dialog an
> event handler should call preventDefault() on the event.
>
> However note that not all browsers support this method, and some
> instead require the event handler to implement one of two legacy
> methods:
>
> - assigning a string to the event's returnValue property
> - returning a string from the event handler.
>
> To combat unwanted pop-ups, browsers may not display prompts created
> in `beforeunload` event handlers unless the page has been interacted
> with, or may even not display them at all.
>
> The HTML specification states that calls to `window.alert()`,
> `window.confirm()`, and `window.prompt()` methods may be ignored during
> this event. See the [HTML specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#user-prompts) for more details.

This should cover most cases. Use a mounting `useEffect` to define the callback, add the event listener, and return the cleanup function to remove the listener.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const unloadCallback = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.returnValue = "";
    return "";
  };

  window.addEventListener("beforeunload", unloadCallback);
  return () => window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", unloadCallback);
}, []);
```

[image]
[image]

[image: Edit put-a-warning-if-page-refresh-in-reactjs]

Comment: Why are you returning empty spaces in the unloadCallback( ) function?

Comment: Also, what about refreshing? This event fires off when there are unsaved changes, but not when page is refreshed.

Comment: @Uzair_07 Regarding the empty strings, this is related to the middle part of the quoted documentation regarding "two legacy methods". Regarding your second question, that's covered by the next line "To combat unwanted pop-ups, browsers may not display prompts created in `beforeunload` event handlers unless the page has been interacted with, or may even not display them at all." In other words, you have to interact with something in the page prior to refreshing the page, and even then the browser may still block it. For the included sandbox simply clicking inside the window was sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can show on unmounting component but you can't show a custom message on window close. Modern browser doesn't support it ([Check browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event#browser_compatibility)). You can set an alert on a click event and there you can set some custom message.

Thank you