# React call function before window/tab close

Tags: javascript, reactjs, window, onbeforeunload

I am trying to call a function when user closes the tab on window. As per my research, i found the following way to achieve the same using **window's beforeunlaod event** :

```
componentDidMount(){
  window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (ev) => {
    this.props.apiCall(); // calling an api to update some data
 })
}
```

It seems that the above code is not working properly as the respective function(apiCall()) is not getting called.

Can someone please help me to resolve the same.

Comment: or you can simply use this package if you just want to get things done and don't wanna know implementation details.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-beforeunload

Comment: You have to use the unload event as well. Here is a working solution for Typescript and functional components: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66171052/6421228

Answer (score 3):

As per [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event), your EventListener should be like this,

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event) => {
  // Cancel the event as stated by the standard.
  event.preventDefault();
  // Chrome requires returnValue to be set.
  event.returnValue = '';

  this.props.apiCall();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @ravibagul91 .Athough I already tried this earlier. It works partially. i.e. after closing the tab, it shows a confirm dialog(window's default one) indicating whether user wants to leave the site or not. As the user clicks the cancel option, then the function get's called, which should not happen. The function should get called once user confirm's and click the "Leave" option/button.

Comment: I would use this answer + an `unload` event listenner (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unload_event) which will trigger your function, not `beforeunload`.

Comment: AS @LLucas already stated, use the unload event as well. Here is a working solution for Typescript and functional components: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66171052/6421228

Comment: Is there any way to do this without the alert box? I noticed that removing `  event.returnValue = '';` prevents the box on chrome, but not on firefox