# logout user when only browser close not on refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, angular, vue.js

Logout the user when he close the browser not on refresh. I use this, it works but the user also logout on refresh the browser

```js
@HostListener('window:unload', ['$event'])
unloadHandler($event) {
  this.LogOutByTabClose();
}

@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
public beforeunloadHandler($event) {
  var msg = this.messageBundle['windowClosemsg']
  $event.returnValue = msg;
  return false
}

LogOutByTabClose() {
  this.LoginService.LogOut(UserService.UserId, UserService.DisplayName, UserService.Apptype).subscribe();
  localStorage.clear();
}
```

Comment: There is no way to know what the user did to exit the page.

Comment: The answer you are looking for is here if it is a React application.. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36358770/12965111

Comment: @graysonmcm . while closing the respective tab of the function. i cant able to call async service call .its my problem .user browser refresh click same time unload function also call

Answer (score 1):

A great solution is to use [Window.sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage). When the user logs in, you set the sessionStorage variable to 'true', when the user logs out you set it to 'false', and the variable will be removed from the sessionStorage when the browser closes.

Comment: while closing the respective tab of the application. i cant able to call async service call .its my problem

Answer (score 0):

I have tried multiple solutions like "`unload`", "`onbeforeunload`", "`performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")[0]`" but nothing worked for me.

I was trying it on the multipage web application.
What worked is mentioned below:

On the page where you want to logout set a local storage variable.

```
localStorage.setItem('isReloaded', true);
```

Now, on your home page

```
componentDidMount(){
if(localStorage.getItem('isReloaded') != null){
  this.logout(); //logout function
}
```

and, inside logout function reset the local storage value

```
logout(){
 //your logout code
 localStorage.removeItem('isReloaded')
}
```

This worked for me very well;

Comment: Do you have an example of using this with a php logout script?