# Can I make a POST request in beforeunload event inside a React component? My code works onclick but not on beforeunload

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to send a POST request whenever the user closes the browser or the tab, and I thought this would be rather simple. I did this:

Added event listener for `beforeunload` on `componentDidMount()`

```
  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.onBeforeUnload);
  }
```

Then created the `onBeforeUnload` function:

```
  onBeforeUnload = () => {
    const headers = {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${getAccessToken()}`,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
    const defaultPresence = {
      presence: 'AVAILABLE',
      message: '',
    };
    const url = getServerURL() + urls.PRESENCE;

    fetch(
      url,
      {
        method: 'POST',
        headers,
        body: JSON.stringify(defaultPresence),
      },
    );
  }
```

Now I know that the `onBeforeUnload` function works fine because when I bind it to an onClick, and click the element, the function fires and I can see that my POST goes through in the network tab of the chrome developer tools.

```
<div onClick={this.onBeforeUnload}>CLICK MEEEEE</div>
```

I can also use Postman to check that I've actually changed the presence to the object I send in the body of my POST request. Sadly, when I close the browser or the tab, onBeforeUpload doesn't seem to send the POST request because I don't see the change in the back-end.

The fact that I need to close my browser to execute the code, prevents me from being able to debug it ( or at least I don't know how ).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66171052/6421228 Can you try with this solution?

Comment: @PriyankKachhela I forgot to mention that I'm using class component so I can't use useEffect. I did try the answer with 21 upvotes but it had the same effect.

Comment: I don't think that will be any problem. You can simply use `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUnmount` instead of `useEffect`