# store data in firestore when Browser Tab is closed or the route is changed (react JS)

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, dom-events, addeventlistener, onbeforeunload

```js
 const handleDraftContracts = async () => {
    console.log('/bruhhhhhhandleDraftContract');
    const paragraphRef: string | any = document.getElementById('contract');
    const contractDetails = {
      contractName: 'House Rental',
      states: {
        amount: amount,
      },
      content: paragraphRef?.textContent,
    };
    await makeDraftContract(contractDetails);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('///////I am hreeeee');
    window.addEventListener('onbeforeunload', (env) => {
      handleDraftContracts();
    });
    return () => {
      console.log('///////removing');
      window.removeEventListener('onbeforeunload', handleDraftContracts);
    };
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);
```

firestore.js

```js
// make Draft Contracts
export async function makeDraftContract(contractDetails: object | any) {
  try {
    console.log("making a draft contract", contractDetails);
    const draftContractRef: any = collection(db,"makeDraftContracts"); 
    let contract = await addDoc(draftContractRef, contractDetails);
    console.log("./////////makeDraftContract", contract);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('////errror in contract Hanlder', error);
  }
}
```

I want to call my `handleDraftContracts` method whenever user closes the tab or changes the route. I am using `onbeforeunload` event. The `handleDraftContracts` is getting called but the tab unloads before Firestore could update the collection. How can I get around this that as the user closes the tab or move to a new route, my firestore method get executed first then the tab gets unloaded ?

Comment: Please look into this question it might help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36355093/reactjs-browser-tab-close-event

Comment: See this answer in the above mentioned question https://stackoverflow.com/a/36358770/14420443

Comment: The Problem is that tab unloads before firebase could update the collection

Answer (score 1):

Try with Beacon api
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Beacon_API

as 'onbeforeunload' cannot make sure you request to server has been made and requests can slow down the browser

componentWillUnmount is like that one, cannot to make long running script.

Comment: With Beacon API, you necessarily have to send an API request, you cannot call the Firestore functions like `.set()`, `doc()` ... Am I right?