# Distinguish between closing the browser and refresh page in React

Tags: reactjs

I want to get event of closing the browser.

```
useEffect(() => {
return () => {
//my code goes here
}
}, []);
```

But it's not running when I close the browser, but running when I refreshing.
Please help me on that.

I changed it to functional component, but still same.

Comment: Maybe take a look into [`beforeunload` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event)

Comment: I've tried it.
But beforeunload is also running when I refreshing.
And I should use functional component and I don't think it has beforeunload

Answer (score 0):

Component unmount won't be called when browser tab is closed.

So the options are

1. Either register an event in an effect

```
useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener("beforeunload", (ev) => {
    // Do something here
  });
}, [])
```

2. Use a library like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63578021/1253103)